# Is “far from perfect” grammatical?

Tags: grammar

#### Is “far from perfect” grammatical?

Here’s my analysis:

1. It’s *ungrammatical* because the object of preposition **from** must be a noun, not an adjective(*perfect*).
2. It’s *grammatical* because **perfect** can be a noun.
3. It’s *grammatical* because **perfect** is the shortened version of the noun phrase “perfect state” or “being perfect”.
4. It’s *grammatical* because “**far from**” is an adverbial phrase.

I think no. 4 is most likely correct. If it’s the case, what does it modify: the verb “**is**” or the adjective “**perfect**”?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. "Far from" can be an adverbial phrase, modifying the adjective "perfect."  We can rewrite "it is far from perfect" using a very common adverb: "not."

> It is not perfect.

to mean essentially the same thing.